# Adding Definitions to Postulates in Agda

Tags: module, agda

Starting with an Agda module that only define a type as a postulate

```
module M where 
  postulate 
   U : Set
```

I want to be able to define U in different ways. For example:

```
module B where 
  open M public 
  -- define U as Bool
```

and

```
module N where 
  open M public 
  -- define U as Nat
```

Is there a way to do this in Agda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't, postulates are abstract.

You can achieve what you want by inverting the order: instead of trying to define `U` inside a `module B` or `N` like you do, instead do

```
module M (U : Set) where
```

and then you instantiate `U` to `Bool` or `Nat`.